saving / loading data
hello i am trying to make a cookie clicker for a school project but i dont know how to save multiple data intov your program u can find the save / load data under here its c# WPF
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var OpgeslagenData = "opslag.txt";
    using(StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(OpgeslagenData))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(globaleDingen.koekjes);
        sw.WriteLine(globaleDingen.aantalUpgraded);
        sw.WriteLine(globaleDingen.klick);
        sw.WriteLine(globaleDingen.upgrade);
        sw.WriteLine(globaleDingen.goldBars);
    }
}

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int koekjes;
    int aantalUpgraded;
    int klick;
    int upgrade;
    int goldBars;
    var OpgeslagenData = "opslag.txt";
    using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(OpgeslagenData))
    {
        koekjes = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine().ElementAt(1));
        aantalUpgraded = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine().ElementAt(2));
        klick = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine().ElementAt(3));
        upgrade = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine().ElementAt(4));
        goldBars = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine().ElementAt(5));

    }
    globaleDingen.koekjes = koekjes;
    globaleDingen.aantalUpgraded = aantalUpgraded;
    globaleDingen.klick = klick;
    globaleDingen.upgrade = upgrade;
    globaleDingen.goldBars = goldBars;
}

i hope anyone could help me please

ElementAt() calls don't make sense, remove them

also you don't need intermediate variables, you can directly assign globaleDingen properties

Do not write Data to a txt file. Use a Database ( maybe a single-file one that comes with its own ORM, like SqlLite, LiteDB, ...) or at least just serialize to / deserialize from JSON (or similar formats). See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to

Use an existing serialization format, this allow libraries to automatically convert objects to and from a serial representation. There are text based formats, like json or xml, that are human readable, and that tend to make debugging problems a lot easier. Or binary formats, like protobuf, that tend to provide better size and performance.
If you just want to save and load a small chunk of data I would recommend using system.text.json:
public class WeatherForecastDTO
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
public void Example()
{
    var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecastDTO
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"),
        TemperatureCelsius = 25,
        Summary = "Hot"
    };

    var fileName = "WeatherForecast.json";
    using (var fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(fs, weatherForecast);
    }

    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecastDTO>(fs);
    }
}

You often want to separate the classes used for serialization from classes containing actual logic, this is sometimes called a "Data Transfer Object" (DTO). Such objects typically need public getter and setters, and a parameterless constructor.
You can often also use attributes and settings to control how the objects are serialized.
The other alternative is a database, possibly an embedded database like SQLite. Often together with a "Object Relational Mapper" (ORM) to do the object to database row conversion. See Getting started with entity framework. Databases are a bit more complex to use, but tend to provide better scaling if you need to process lots of objects.
